Why does the browser not send referer when using egg's ctx.redirect?
I used egg to start two services, which can be accessed at test1.com and test2.com respectively.
test1.com redirects to test2.com via ctx.redirect.
// test1 egg
router.get('/render', controller.home.render);

async render() {
    const { ctx } = this;
    ctx.redirect('https://test2.moomoo.com');
}

// test2 egg
async render() {
    const { ctx } = this;
    console.log('ctx.header.referer', ctx.header.referer);
    await this.ctx.render('/index.html', {
      data: 'test2',
    });
}

I found that the browser will not display referer at this time.
The values ​​of ctx.header.referer and document.referrer are both empty
Why is this?
But when I redirect via window.location, referer is displayed
I wish when I use ctx.redirect to redirect to test2, referer will show test1

The egg tag you used in your tags is about a python thing and most certainly not related to your problem. Couldn't find a respective tag for the egg.js framework you are probably referring to
